# JavaScript date comparison

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compare 2 dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-2-dates-with-javascript)

I haven't done much JavaScript. I am trying to compare two dates. From jconsole:

```
a = ["01/01/2010","01/02/2010","01/03/2010"]

date1 = new Date('01/02/2010')
Sat Jan 02 2010 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)

date2 = new Date(a[1])
Sat Jan 02 2010 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)

date1 == date2
false
```

Can someone tell me why this does not match?

Comment: It is interesting to note that both `>=` and `<=` return `true` in this case, but `==` gives `false`. Another JavaScript miracle.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your comparison is returning false because `date1` and `date2` are simply references to different objects, and you are actually comparing these references.

To do a proper comparison of the date values, you can use the [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Date/getTime) method as follows:

```
date1.getTime() === date2.getTime();   // returns true
```

Comment: okay thanks. So '===' also compares type. Do '<=' and '>=' also compare type?

Comment: @ash34: Yes it is generally recommended to use `===` instead of `==`. You may also want to check out this reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators. First of all note the part where it says: "Two objects are strictly equal if they refer to the same Object."... Also check the description of the different comparison operators.