# match two datetimes in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I have two dates :

date1 = "2013-07-08 12:30:00"

date2 = "2013-07-08 13:30:00"

Now in javascript i want to match these two dates and its they dont match than i want to delete the appointment and if they match than nothing to do.

I tried this code but its not working :

```
  if(date1 == date2)// Event already exists
  {
      // do nothing
  }
  else
  {
      // delete the record.
  }
```

I tried to compare with "new Date(date1) == new Date(date2)" also but its not working either.

There is some problem in my code or date format. can anyone know how to do this and where i am wrong in this code ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The 2 dates are never equal as it not only checks for the day , but also the time.. So when they are converted to a DateTime object it never matched

Comment: What "is not working" exactly?  When comparing as strings, the values you provided worked fine for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752532/javascript-date-comparison

Comment: Try 2013/07/08 12:30:00, instead of 2013-07-08 12:30:00, also try comparing with > or < instead of ==

Comment: actually i meant substracting date1 from date2 and comparing the difference. but @adeneo's answer seems good

Comment: Be careful: new Date("2013-07-08 12:30:00") on my pc throws an invalid date error ..probably has to do with my navigator localization, so keep that in mind ..ahh works when i do this: new Date("2013-07-08T12:30:00")

Comment: Ya in my pc also it gives invalid date error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different objects are never the same, you have to compare the numbers that make up the unix timestamp:

```
var date1 = "2013-07-08 12:30:00",
    date2 = "2013-07-08 13:30:00";

var d1 = new Date(date1);
var d2 = new Date(date2);

if (d1.getTime() == d2.getTime()) {

}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Uy8Jp/)

Comment: Thanks adeneo. But all the time it gives me false.

Comment: @Mausami it should, 12:30 isn't the same as 13:30

Comment: yea sorry. It was my mistake.. Thanks a lott HMR and adeneo.

Answer (score 0):

it works for me:

```
var date1 = "2013-07-08 12:30:00";

var date2 = "2013-07-08 12:30:00";
var date3 = "2013-07-08 12:00:00";

console.log(date1 == date2); //true
console.log(date1 == date3); //false
```

[Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gLKHf/2/)

Comment: Naming your variables date doesn't make them date objects. When comparing primative types you should use ===

Comment: Please change the names of variables according to your choice and also use ===, now check if it gives you the answer or not. please use the fiddle link i have provided

Answer (score 0):

Adeno has a valid answer but will fail if the dates are milliseconds appart (not the case in OP's example if you use a valid date string). To be sure you're comparing dates by minutes or days you can do:

```
function sameTime(dt1,dt2){
  //round the dates to the minutes
  var t1=new Date(dt1);
  var t2=new Date(dt2);
  t1.setSeconds(0,0);
  t2.setSeconds(0,0);
  return t1.toString()===t2.toString();
}
function sameDay(dt1,dt2){
  //round the dates to the day
  var t1=new Date(dt1);
  var t2=new Date(dt2);
  t1.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  t2.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  return t1.toString()===t2.toString();
}
function sameMonth(dt1,dt2){
  //round the dates to the month
  var t1=new Date(dt1);
  var t2=new Date(dt2);
  t1.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  t2.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  t1.setDate(1);
  t2.setDate(1);
  return t1.toString()===t2.toString();
}
var date1 = "2013-07-08T12:30:00",
    date2 = "2013-07-08T13:30:00";
var d1 = new Date(date1);
var d2 = new Date(date2);

console.log(sameTime(d1,d2));//precise to the minute
console.log(sameDay(d1,d2));//precise to the day
console.log(sameMonth(d1,d2));//precise to the month
```